# Performing ANOVA/Regression on Percentage Data

Tags: regression, anova

I'm trying to see if there are any significant differences in 3 data sets that I have. The data is taken from around 1000 participants, each within different families who tried an experiment to see whether or not they tasted a particular flavour (salt, sour, sweet, bitter, umami) on the same part of their tongue (front, back, left, right, middle).

The expected percentage of a non-related adult and child was tasting the flavour in the same place was calculated by multiplying the sum of percentages that an over-18 and under-18 would taste for one particular flavour (for example salt) would be p(under18_salt_left)*p(over18_salt_left) + p(under18_salt_right)*p(over18_salt_right) +...

The percentages of related adults and children were calculated by other methods, essentially contributing as 1 if there was a match between an adult and a child.

This resulted in the following:

[image: Analysis Results]

How should I go about in finding out if there is a significant difference between say the percentage of a father/child match and the expected probability (two unrelated participants).

EDIT (07/07/2014)

The format of the spreadsheet being used to calculate is shown below, where conditional IF statements give a value of "1" for each flavour if there is a match between "Father" and "Child1" given that "Family Number" is the same.

[image: Matching Families]

Answer (score 1):

I would go back to the raw data and simply do a linear model. If you sampled families and took everyone within each family, then you would have a random effect for family. The fixed effects are family role (mother, father or child) and flavour (Sweet, Sour, etc). If I have understood this correctly, flavour is nested within person and person is nested within family. Flavour is crossed with family role.

I don't quite understand how the parts of the tongue fit in with the flavours, but I assume that is another fixed effect. The response is a 0 or 1, depending on whether the flavour was tasted or not in that particular location. Flavour is crossed with tongue location.

Get rid of the percentages. They don't help.

Comment: Sorry - I neglected to mention the original format of the database I used. Each family is given a separate number, which increments by 1 with each family, for example the first family of three may consist of a Father, Child1, Child2, who will all have "Family Number"= 1. I realise this might not be the place for Excel matters, but when copying into Excel I created conditional IF statements which gave a value of "1" for each flavour if there is a match between "Father" and "Child1" given that "Family Number" is the same (See edited original post).

Comment: In performing linear regression, do I not have two categorical variables in Family Number and Location? Apologies but analyzing data of this sort is new to me.

Comment: In addition to this, how am I able to use the raw data in order to know whether there is a match between two unrelated participants without knowing the probabilities of it occurring?

Comment: Realised in the end that a two-tailed Chi-squared test was probably the best approach for the data.